# Python regex extract string multiline

Tags: python, regex

From this string:

```
s = 'OBS VA DTG:           07/1200Z\r\r\nEST VA CLD:           SFC/FL200 S2115 W17500 - S2015 W17000 - S2415\r\r\n                      W16930 - S2300 W17815 - S2030 W17615 - S2030\r\r\n                      W17515 - S2115 W17500 FL200/600 NO VA EXP\r\r\nFCST VA CLD+6 HR:     07/1800Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP\r\r\nFCST VA CLD+12 HR:    08/0000Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP\r\r\nFCST VA CLD+18 HR:    08/0600Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP\r\r\n'
```

Pretty printed is:

```
OBS VA DTG:           07/1200Z
EST VA CLD:           SFC/FL200 S2115 W17500 - S2015 W17000 - S2415
                      W16930 - S2300 W17815 - S2030 W17615 - S2030
                      W17515 - S2115 W17500 FL200/600 NO VA EXP
FCST VA CLD+6 HR:     07/1800Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP
FCST VA CLD+12 HR:    08/0000Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP
FCST VA CLD+18 HR:    08/0600Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP
```

I'd like a regular expression to extract the EST VA CLD value. That should be the output:

```
SFC/FL200 S2115 W17500 - S2015 W17000 - S2415
W16930 - S2300 W17815 - S2030 W17615 - S2030
W17515 - S2115 W17500 FL200/600 NO VA EXP
```

I've tried:

```
>>> match = re.search(r"EST VA CLD:(.+)\n.+:",s,re.DOTALL)
>>> print match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EST VA CLD:\s*([\s\S]+?)\n(?=[^:\n]*:)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/22#python

Comment: Could you explain what mean [\s\S]+??

Comment: @alasarr `[\s\S]` means capture `space` and `non space` characters.This will span multple lines as `\s` captures `\n` as well.So u need not use `s` flag

Comment: can you also explains ^:\n ?

Comment: @alasarr `[^\n:]*:` means there should not be `:` and ` \n`  and other characters untill `:` if found.

Answer (score 0):

How about;

```
s = 'OBS VA DTG:           07/1200Z\r\r\nEST VA CLD:           SFC/FL200 S2115 W17500 - S2015 W17000 - S2415\r\r\n                      W16930 - S2300 W17815 - S2030 W17615 - S2030\r\r\n                      W17515 - S2115 W17500 FL200/600 NO VA EXP\r\r\nFCST VA CLD+6 HR:     07/1800Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP\r\r\nFCST VA CLD+12 HR:    08/0000Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP\r\r\nFCST VA CLD+18 HR:    08/0600Z SFC/FL600 NO VA EXP\r\r\n'
t = s.split()

print (" ".join(t[t.index("CLD:")+1:t.index("FCST")]))
```